# Synchronize and sort two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to synchronize two arrays.

First array:

```
'hi' => "Hello",
'bye'=> "Bye bye",
'w'=>"what",
```

Second array:

```
'hi' => "Hello",
'bye'=> "Bye bye",
'we'=>"where",
'w'=>"what",
```

1. I want sort them by key
2. Add keys from second array which are not in the first
3. Display the array

Like here they are sorted by key (abc..):

```
'bye'=> "Bye bye",
'hi' => "Hello",
'w'=>"what", 
'we'=>"where",
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Seems like a legitimate question to me, or at least I understood it.

Comment: never worry about your english, as long as it's clear what you want, we can always edit your english, what we cannot edit is lack of info in your question. This is why your question got closed.  It's almost a question, but we don't know how to answer it. It's usually best to include the sourcecode you've got and tell us what you want it to do and what's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Example:

```
$array1 = array(
    'hi' => "Hello",
    'bye'=> "Bye bye",
    'w'=>"what",
);

$array2 = array(
    'hi' => "Hello",
    'bye'=> "Bye bye",
    'we'=>"where",
    'w'=>"what",
);

$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
ksort($array3);
```

See it in action here: http://codepad.org/D2piffFE.

As far as your #3 goes, "display the array", that's completely up to you. Use a `foreach` loop or `implode()`

Comment: this display once time double key from both arrays and single keys from both arrays.
I want to display one time double keys like above example but single keys only from array1 , so I want to ignore single keys from array2.
Is possible this?

Comment: @goni: I have no idea what you're asking now. This provides the output you asked for. You can't have duplicate keys in an array.

Comment: I give you an example with 3 or 4 key=>value but there are more and with different key=>value in my case. 
Anyway thank you!

Comment: @goni: Did you even try this to confirm it is not what you want?